# Air Conditioner blows directly to my desk; how can I stop this?

Tags: work-environment, temperature

Our team recently moved floor. Ever since I am distracted with the cold. The room temperature is 24 Degrees Celsius but there is AC blowing cold air onto the back of my head. The pages of my notepad on my desk move in the breeze. The only other desk available is also under an air vent. It is better than my desk, but I don't want to sit anywhere near a AC vent anymore.

I find it embarrassing to complain about this sort of thing.

Is it a reasonable thing to complain about? I know lots of people have to work outside in the winter and I am sitting in my office complaining.

What is the best solution for me?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Spoken to anybody about it yet?

Comment: Location? that will be a factor and the answer is not "office"...

Comment: Cardboard and duct tape

Comment: @A.S, nice use of the "No true Scotsman" fallacy. Being too cold or too hot at work can be a real distraction and has nothing to do with a person's ability to be adaptable or the strength of their character. Also, companies aren't loyal to their employees, normally, so I never suggest being 100% loyal to a company. A company would fire an employee for being as annoying as an AC vent, so it's more than justified to see if the OP can comment to their boss about it.

Comment: I've done the cardboard trick.  We had circular diffusers in the ceiling.  We cut 4 pie-shaped pieces of cardboard, painted them black so they would not be obvious to maintenance, and just slid them up into the diffuser,

Comment: Or after consulting your boss, you could just have your facilities guy buy some of those deflectors https://www.amazon.com/s?k=air+condition+redirect&ref=nb_sb_noss They're magnetic. Some are transparent. Some are even adjustable. And most are not expensive at all.

Comment: Tell HR what you just told here

Comment: @computercarguy Appreciate the response! I hope it was obvious enough that my comment was a combination of sound advice and tongue-in-cheek humor. Sometimes I wonder if folks on this site have that 6th sense...Also for some reason I am not able to see my comment anymore. If some square voted to delete it, too bad for them! Hope it wasn't you, no offense. Gotta be tough living in today's world of surreal politics, wound up social discourse, and grotesque political correctness. I will stay optimistic though.

Comment: @A.S, unfortunately, sarcasm doesn't translate over text very well, so it needs to be made 100% absolutely blatantly obvious. There are plenty of people who have a hard time detecting that type of tongue-in-cheek humor IRL, as you probably already know, and I'm sure many of them are on these SE/SO sites. I'll remind you to please use humor wisely on these sites. And no, I didn't detect the humor in your comment.

Comment: @computercarguy Well, that explains it!

Comment: I've done some measurements. HSE UK states that "air temperature alone is not a valid or accurate indicator of thermal comfort" Room temperature is pretty good. I think the problem is actually humidity + air velocity. 24% humidity today for example. Bit more to the story as well. I developed eczema a couple of months after starting this job. I don't know if it is a co-incidence or not.

Answer (score 20):

> What is the best solution for me?

I suggest you **approach HR or your manager, and tell them about this.**

Say that currently the AC is *distracting you from your work*, and ask what can be done to solve it. You can then work on a solution that is Ok for everybody.

Taking a guess, I assume that the AC stream can be redirected, in a way that it does not point directly to you. Perhaps that is a better alternative than to relocate to another desk or something else.

Comment: Generally mentioned on this forum is "HR is not your friend", in that they are there to deal with legal and press matters of the company. Going to the manager is a good suggestion, though.

Comment: @computercarguy in this situation, HR can be your friend :) I think you are stretching that saying a bit...

Comment: @DarkCygnus, only if the OP goes through the proper channels first and doesn't get any responses. The OP would also have to document all contacts and responses (or lack thereof) to have a chance that HR would be able to do anything for them.

Comment: I'd first ask the facilities manager (or department) instead of HR

Comment: +1.  Keep in mind, OP, that the business *wants you to be productive*.  If there's a simple easy change that will make you more productive, they will do that in a heartbeat.  All it takes is you telling them about what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 9):

Don't be embarrassed to mention this stuff.  It is routine work to adjust the ventilation to match the needs of the occupants of an office building. That is especially true if your new floor was recently renovated.  There's no way for the heating / ventilation / air conditioning (HVAC) people to know unless you tell them.